# ASP.NET MVC View Profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an `Html.Actionlink` to which I am trying to add a "class" and an ActiveClass.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Account", null, 
    new {@class ="some-class"}, 
    Html.RenderLinkClassIfActive("Home", "Account", "active"))  %>
```

However, this doesn't work. What can I differently to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add the `RenderLinkClassIfActive` code please?

UPDATE: Supposing `Html.RenderLinkClassIfActive("Home", "Account", "active")` returns a class if active try:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Account", null, new {@class ="some-class " + Html.RenderLinkClassIfActive("Home", "Account", "active") } )%>
```

Comment: sure its (actionName, controllerName, className) - which just shows the link has been selected